# JNI String return value

Tags: java, c++, string, java-native-interface

I have a Java instance method which returns a String and I'm calling this method through JNI in C++. I have written the following code:

```
const char *DiagLayerContainer_getDESC(JNIEnv *env, jobject diagLayer) {
    jclass diagLayerClass = env->FindClass(PARSER_CLASS);
    jmethodID getDESCDiagLayerMethodID = env->GetMethodID(diagLayerClass, "getDESCDiagLayer", "(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;");
    jstring returnString = (jstring) env->CallObjectMethod(diagLayer, getDESCDiagLayerMethodID);
    return env->GetStringUTFChars(returnString, JNI_FALSE);
}
```

How do I get the string and convert it to a const char *?

My program crashes on the last line with access violation to 0x00000000. returnString is not NULL.

Comment: Run your code in a debugger, and examine the state of the process right at the point of the crash.

Comment: It crashes here (jni.h):
    const char* GetStringUTFChars(jstring str, jboolean *isCopy) {
        return functions->GetStringUTFChars(this,str,isCopy);
    }
without any chance to go deeper with the debugger

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [`GetStringUTFChars`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp17265), the last parameter is a pointer to `jboolean`.

Change

```
return env->GetStringUTFChars(returnString, JNI_FALSE);
```

to

```
return env->GetStringUTFChars(returnString, NULL);
```

Or better yet, return a `std::string`

```
std::string DiagLayerContainer_getDESC(...) {
    ...
    const char *js = env->GetStringUTFChars(returnString, NULL);
    std::string cs(js);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(returnString, js);
    return cs;
}
```

I've built a similar simple example and the code as is, seems fine so far.

Although, there are two possible error sources.

The first one is the method signature. Try `"()Ljava/lang/String;"` instead of `"(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/String;"`.

The second one is in the java source itself. If the java method returns a null string, `CallObjectMethod()` will return a NULL `jstring` and `GetStringUTFChars()` fails.

Add a

```
if (returnString == NULL)
    return NULL;
```

after `CallObjectMethod()`.

So look into the java source and see, whether the method `getDESCDiagLayer()` might return a null string.

Comment: If `isCopy` is false and `returnString` goes out of scope (i.e. through an explicit or implicit `PopLocalFrame`), you'll have a dangling pointer. You should `strdup()` the result of `GetStringUTFChars`, return that, and call `ReleaseStringUTFChars`. Later, dispose of the copy with `free()`, as usual in native code.

Comment: strdup() is replaced with std::string(), which will copy new allocated string itself.

Comment: How can I print returnString in Logcat?

Comment: What do you mean by Logcat? Android's Logcat?

Comment: @K.Sopheak, you can use [__android_log_write](https://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group/logging#group___logging_1ga32a7173b092ec978b50490bd12ee523b)