# How JNI takes the returned value-object of native method

Tags: java, jvm, java-native-interface

My question is how the JNI takes the returned value of a native method and give it to the JVM (push into native stack).

For example if i have a native method `toString`, and the JVM knows where is the code of toString method, how JNI call the method?

Comment: WTF?  What does the return value of a JNI call have to do with a return value from "system()".  Besides the word "return??? See also: [JNI String return value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268426/jni-string-return-value)

Comment: yes i agree with you, but my question is how calls a native method, and then how takes the returned value. If you want a different question but the same thing : How with C++ can I call a function from a other file and take the returned value from it.(without serialization)

Comment: @paulsm4 i want to know how this virtual machine works and no how to convert an array of chars to java string.

Comment: SUGGESTION: Study *ONE* method of "passing a return value" for *ONE* language on *ONE* platform.  Understand how that works.  Then apply that understanding by comparing with some *DIFFERENT* "return value" on some *DIFFERENT* platform and language (for example, Java JNI).  Good article about C++ function calls: [x86 calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions)

Answer (score 0):

Java does not receive C-style array of chars from native method. The callee builds a Java Object (e.g., String) and passes it by reference to the caller. With *primitive* types, e.g. **int**, the result is passed by value, but implementation details are private to JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Java only supports primitives and references. There is no String object types passed or return, only every a *reference* to a String.  This reference is a `void *` from a C point of view and no conversion occurs to the data in the object.

> i want to know how this virtual machine works and no how to convert an array of chars to java string

[Convert char* to jstring in JNI, when char* is passed using va_arg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939349/convert-char-to-jstring-in-jni-when-char-is-passed-using-va-arg)